# Parse NSString to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I am trying to parse an NSString to NSArray but couldn't get any success. Here is my String: `NSString *points = @"[[51.471914582, -0.12274114637],[51.47287707533, -0.12163608379]]";`

I want this string mapped to NSArray.

```
NSArray *tempArray = points;
```

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString`, `stringByReplaceingString`, regex, etc. What's have you tried?

Comment: Try this: NSArray* arrayOfStrings = [points componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Comment: @Idrees Is that string actually in JSON format?

Comment: @Tanuj But this will separate the inner values as well. I just needed [51.471914582, -0.12274114637] as an Object of NSArray. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, code golf (untested):

```
NSString *points = @"[[51.471914582, -0.12274114637],[51.47287707533, -0.12163608379]]";
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *pointsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[points dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];
for (NSArray *point in pointsArray) {
    NSAssert([point count] == 2, @"Invalid point");
    // do thing with point
    CGPoint pt = CGPointMake([point[0] floatValue], [point[1] floatValue]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome . You Rock :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you plz try this, May it solve your problem,

```
NSString *points = @"[[51.471914582, -0.12274114637],[51.47287707533, -0.12163608379]]";
NSArray* arrayOfStrings = [points componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfStrings);
NSMutableArray *copyArray = [arrayOfStrings mutableCopy];
NSMutableString *stringFirst = (NSMutableString *)[copyArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableString *stringLast = (NSMutableString *)[copyArray lastObject];
stringFirst=[stringFirst substringFromIndex:1];
stringLast=[stringLast substringToIndex:stringLast.length-1];
[copyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:stringFirst];
[copyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:(copyArray.count-1) withObject:stringLast];

NSMutableArray *yourarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<=(copyArray.count/2); i+=2) {
    [yourarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[copyArray objectAtIndex:i], [copyArray objectAtIndex:i+1]]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",yourarray);
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

That string looks like JSON so you can use `NSJSONSerialization`

```
NSData * data = [points dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * arrayOfPointArrays = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```